# Creating a table footer line to display results 1 to n

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, table-footer

Let's say I had a table with 100 results in it. How would i use JS to add a footer line to the table that contains something like:

Displaying results 26-50 out of 100

And then have something like:

Page: 1 **2** 3 4

I'd like to be able to just click on the page numbers and have it toggle between which set of results to show me. I.e. if i click on the number 1 it will display results 1-25, and if i click on the number 3 it will display results 51-75. I'd like to do this without forcing the page to reload.

I was thinking that basically you would somehow use onclick to change the class of the items from display: none to display: block but I'm not really sure

Comment: Take a look at the DataTables plugin.  It does this and much much more very easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you see the Jquery Datatable plugin ?

https://datatables.net/

It does the job.

Comment: Awesome, that looks like exactly what I need. I'll take a look, thanks